# passing string around question

Tags: c++

I have a member function like

```
setResult(const std::string &s)
{
         this->m_result = s;
}
```

After checking, I found `this->m_result`'s address is the same as `s`. Will `m_result` disappear (or become garbage) when `s` goes out of scope if `s` is a stack object?

Comment: How did you do that check? And what is the type of m_result?

Comment: What is m_result declared as?

Comment: To all those who answered - why not wait until the OP responds to my comment?

Comment: "passing string around question" - not the best title.

Comment: it is weird that I get the same address yesterday. Now they are different address. I will try to repro later

Comment: Perhaps we can help you understand why the results change from yesterday to today, if you could answer @Neil's questions. How did you do that check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not; if `m_result` is a std::string, it will deep-copy the data contents.

Anyway, in places like assignment operators, you'd normally check against this kind of self-assignment.  The idiom is:

```
obj& operator=(const obj& o) {
    if ( this != &o ) // ...
}
```

The same goes for your case, where you could potentially check it `&m_result` is different from the passed in string.  But std::string are usually implemented so that self-copying is OK.

Comment: Also note @larsmans's reply about m_result being a reference, in which case you've got a problem.

Comment: In a copy constructor, self-assignment is by definition not possible.

Answer (score -1):

Effectively `s` is no stack object, as it's a reference (the reference itself is a stack object, but the string is not). Actually `this->m_result` can only have the same address as s, if you passed `this->m_result` to `testResult`, but although self-assignment is quite useless, in this case it doesn't do any harm.

**EDIT:** Another case could be, that `this->m_result` is not a std::string but a reference to it. Then you got a problem as you got a reference to a destroyed object. Remember, a reference is nothing more than a pointer (just more comfortable to use and with reduced functionalty).